# Are there weapons that use armor piercing ammo/projectiles?

Tags: far-cry-3

I have observed that explosions, incendiary projectiles, [explosive projectiles (AMR - signature Z93 sniper rifle)](http://www.ign.com/wikis/far-cry-3/AMR), [hitting armored enemies at their non-armored parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyDjw.jpg) and use of a [certain takedown skill](http://www.ign.com/wikis/far-cry-3/The_Shark), are effective ways to take down armored enemies.

Aside from those, I would like to know if there are weapons that use *armor piercing projectiles* (effective at *hitting* armored enemies even in armor-covered parts of their bodies). I'm particularly interested in *silent*, armor piercing weapons (if they exist), as most methods of effectively killing armored enemies are noisy (except for the takedown skill).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very least the Z93 has armor piercing projectiles.
I was able to headshot LMG/flamethrower enemies, who wear an armored helmet, with this sniper rifle. I was not able to headshot them with the M-700.
The ingame description of the Z93 also states that it uses .50 caliber rounds. Rounds of that caliber are normally armor piercing.
Ingame description of the Z93:

> "No rifle hits harder at long range than this .50 caliber beast. Simply put, it kills what it hits."

I also guess that the D50 is loaded with .50 caliber rounds, hence the 50 in the name. Plus its counterpart in reality is able to shoot .50 caliber rounds, but there is no written ingame evidence that this gun actually carries .50 caliber rounds.

*Edit:*
Maybe the .44 Revolver is armor piercing, because of the high caliber.
 I also noticed the Shredder to be quite effective against armored enemies, yet i cannot confirm if it's armor piercing, as there is no written ingame proof.

Comment: Aside from the Z93 (and possibly, the D50), any other weapons with armor piercing projectiles?

Comment: The Z93 I can definitely confirm. The D50 is a legimite guess. For the rest i could not find proof for armor piercing abilities.

Comment: Also please see the edit to my answer.

Comment: There seems to be a damage bonus for hitting surprised enemies. If I headshot an armored enemy with the Z93 who is unaware of me, it kills him. If he's aware, one shot never cuts it. Playing on Veteran, anyway. So it may not actually be armor-piercing, just "high damage that sometimes gets a large enough multiplier to kill them"

Answer (score 0):

The signature Z93 sniper rifle, called AMR (anti-materiel rifle) and unlocked at shops for $4800 after collecting 20 relics, fires special explosive rounds that are effective against armor. Grenade launchers, as well as explosive and incendiary arrows, are also effective.

Comment: I have mentioned those in my question. Not including those explosive or incendiary weapons/ammunition, are there weapons that use ammo/projectiles that are *armor piercing*?

Comment: Oh, blimey, you did. I think that's that.

Answer (score -1):

The AMR can blow up a car in one shot and can kill Heavy Armour enemies in one shot, even on the body. It costs $4800 in the store, and is a signature weapon. Although it isn't silenced I would recommend it.

Comment: The AMR is indirectly mentioned and linked in the question with "explosive projectiles".